# How can I remove a character from message.content?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I'm currently trying to make my bot say whatever I say. So, the bot gets activated if my message starts with the "§" symbol. It's supposed to delete my message, delete the "§" character out of it, and then post it without that symbol in that same chat.

I've tried a few things, including subtracting the symbol or making it a string, but nothing has worked. So, what can I do?

```
@client.event
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('§'):
        channel1 = message.channel
        await message.delete()
        await channel1.send(f'{message.content}' - '§')
```

Here, I get an error message saying:

```
await channel1.send(f'{message.content}' - '§')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

How can I make it so that the "§" symbol gets deleted from the message?

Comment: Simply remove the first character from the string using the corresponding string slice => `message.content[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the prefix with an empty string

```py
await channel1.send(f"{message.content.replace('§', '')}")
```

Comment: Note that this will remove every occurrence of the character in the string and not only the first one.

Comment: In that case, add the third parameter which specifies how much occurence it will replace.

Comment: Okay, how do I do that? Could you show me an example? Sorry, I'm not so knowledgable in coding. Currently learning it.

Comment: ... or just drop the first character since it's presence is already tested with `message.starstwith('§')`=> `await channel1.send(message.content[1:])`. Alternative proposed by @Nhalrath is `await channel1.send(message.content.replace'('§', '', 1)`. Both will lead to the same result with your current code sample.